# “when r isn’t a field, it is no longer true that they are the only modules”

Tags: abstract-algebra

What does this sentence mean? My book just introduced modules and was talking about The modules $R^n$ of $r$ vectors.

Comment: If $R$ is a ring that’s not a field, then there’s an ideal $I$ other than $\{0\}$ and $R$ itself. Then, for example, $I$ is a module not of the form $R^n$; also $R/I$ is not of form $R^n$.

Comment: @Lubin that makes a lot of sense. Thank you

Comment: In Lubin's comment we should emphasize *one-sided ideals*. As I'm sure he knows, there are non-fields with no non-trivial ideals, but a non-invertible non-zero element generates a non-trivial left ideal.

Comment: There are rings $R$ that have ideals $I$ for which $R/I$ is actually of the form $R^n$ (for any $n\ge1$, for that matter), such as $R=k[x_1,x_2,\dots]$ and $I=(x_1)$.